# Tool to Convert External CSS to Inline CSS in Ruby?

Tags: css, google-docs, html-parser, inline-styles

I am messing around with GoogleDocs and it has very very primitive CSS support.  If you upload an MSWord .doc or an HTML file and export it as HTML, all styles are applied inline.  They have a style block in the html file, but when you upload the HTML file back to google docs, it doesn't apply any non-inline styles.

So I was thinking "maybe there's a ruby tool for this".  Is there anything out there I could use to take some CSS and have it parse it into the HTML nodes, maybe some nokogiri plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out alexdunae's Premailer on GitHub:
http://github.com/alexdunae/premailer

Never tried it by myself, just stumbled upon. Maybe it helps.

Comment: this also looks great, but is not rails-integrated (just for those out there who are looking for that).

Comment: I use Premailer at putsmail.com, it works like a charm. You can test it online.

Answer (score 2):

MailStyle is another solution: http://github.com/purify/mail_style

Looks like it has easy rails integration (actionmailer, sass), but I'm not sure that's what you are/were looking for.

Comment: this looks great, and integrates with rails

Answer (score 1):

Ruby Toolbox has a [list of even more options](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Inline_CSS_for_E-Mail). [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca) is the most used, though [Roadie](https://github.com/mange/roadie#readme) has been updated more recently.